# Change the values for multiple input field with same id in react js

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am trying to change the value of price for multiple occurrences of same ID in react js.

I am able to change the value in the state array, but I also want to display the changed value on the front end.

Here is the code snippet:
React JS component: To render all the selected items. Onchange function changes the value of price for occurrences of "item.id".

```
<CenterAlignedColumnContainer>
            <div />
            {showBr &&
              finalbrArray.map((item, index) => {
                return (
                  <CenterAlignedRowContainer>
                    <h1>{item.name}</h1>
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      name="price"
                      defaultValue={item.price}
                      onClick={handleTextClick}
                      onChange={handleTextClick(item.id)}
                    />
                  </CenterAlignedRowContainer>
                );
              })}
          </CenterAlignedColumnContainer>
```

```
  const handleTextClick = id => e => {
  
    finalbrArray
      .filter(br => br.id === id)
      .forEach(item => {
        item.price = e.target.value;
      });

    console.table(finalbrArray);
  };
```

The handleTextClick function changes my finalbrArrray to

```
[{
    id: 136,
    name: 'Chocolate - Chips Compound',
    price: '235.92'
  },
  {
    id: 137,
    name: 'Appetizer - Chicken Satay',
    price: '199.69'
  },
  {
    id: 138,
    name: 'Compound - Mocha',
    price: '431.16'
  },
  {
    id: 139,
    name: 'Syrup - Chocolate',
    **price: '427.25'**
  },
  {
    id: 139,
    name: 'Syrup - Chocolate',
    **price: '427.25'**
  },
  {
    id: 140,
    name: 'Lamb - Leg, Boneless',
    price: '183.44'
  },
  {
    id: 141,
    name: 'Jam - Blackberry, 20 Ml Jar',
    price: '493.03'
  },
  {
    id: 142,
    name: 'Lid - 3oz Med Rec',
    price: '259.42'
  }
]
```

My objective is to reflect the same value at the both the indexes at front end as well..

Comment: You need to put the finalbrArray to state and modify that state using `setState()`. This explains the basics about state: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

Comment: Hi Christian, I made change to the code and set the state using.  Usestate.

Comment: I am running into a bug, i.e. every time I modify the array in state. Input box looses the focus. I have to select the input box every time I make change. How do I avoid this

Comment: const handleTextClick = id => e => {
    

    finalbrArray
      .filter(br => br.id === id)
      .forEach(item => {
        item.price = e.target.value;
      });

    const updatedBaseRecpie = [...finalbrArray];
    

    setFinalBr(updatedBaseRecpie);
  };

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-chatterjee-3kexu?file=/src/Test.js

Comment: Please refer to this sandbox link for the focus lost problem on input box

Comment: It is because of the line `key={uuid()}`. Remove it and instead add `key={item.id}` to the outermost `<div>` of the return value of the lambda passed to the `map()` function. Whenever you're returning a react component from a lambda that you pass to `map()` like that it's that component that needs to have a key. `uuid()` isn't apporpridate as key because the point of that key is that it stays the same throughout re-renders which `uuid()` doesn't.

Comment: Additionally, instead of `defaultValue={item.price}` just use `value={item.price}`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Christian it solved the issue.. I am  posting answer to the question for future reference or I send it to you and you post it.. Do let me know

Comment: No problem, it's ok if you post it yourself.